# Query to show second degree (indirect) relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with Books, Chapters, and Characters. Books contain Chapters, and Chapters mention Characters. I want to write a query showing me the 10 Characters that appear in most books, together with the books they appear in.

Supposing that my problem is a bit simpler, I can easily write a query showing me the 10 Characters that appear in most chapters:

```
MATCH (chapter)-[:MENTIONS]->(character)
RETURN character,
COLLECT(chapter) as chapters
ORDER BY SIZE(chapters) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This query above is working fine. Now I'm attempting to write a similar query that shows books rather than chapters:

```
MATCH (book)-[:CONTAINS]->(chapter)-[:MENTIONS]->(character)
RETURN character,
COLLECT(book) as books
ORDER BY SIZE(books) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This query seems to work fine, but it just reports a bunch of characters and books without any relationship, because there is no direct relationship between books and characters. Can neo4j infer these indirect relationships and show them in the query without me having to modify the data and manually insert for each pattern

```
(book)-[:CONTAINS]->(chapter)-[:MENTIONS]->(character)
```

a new relationship

```
(book)-[:TALKS_ABOUT]->(character)
```

?

Comment: What type of relationships you need in result of query?

Comment: I'm a little confused...the results of your query should show a character and the collection of books they've appeared in ordered by the number of books they've appeared in (though you may need `COLLECT(DISTINCT book) as books` to get rid of duplicates in your collections). You say that it reports characters and books without any relationship, but there's clearly an indirect relationship, as evidenced by your match. What in the results isn't working for you?

Comment: @stdob: I need a type of relationship that is not in the model, and that I'd like to avoid adding manually as I said in the example in the last paragraph. The relationship should show a link between characters and books.

Comment: @InverseFalcon: I would like the results to show the relationship between the retrieved characters, and the books where they appear. Currently, what I see is just 10 character nodes plus a number of book nodes, but I cannot track back from a single character to the books it appears in, unless I double click the character node and expand it to also show chapters.

Comment: Ah, you're interested in the graph results view, not the actual row data returned. APOC's virtual relationships are the way to go here, stdob-- has a great example of usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's look like you need virtual relationships. You can try [`apoc.create.vRelationship`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_virtual_nodes_rels):

```
MATCH (book)-[:CONTAINS]->(chapter)-[:MENTIONS]->(character)
WITH character, 
     COLLECT(distinct book) as books 
     ORDER BY SIZE(books) DESC LIMIT 10
UNWIND books as book
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(book,'TALKS_ABOUT',{}, character) yield rel
RETURN character, collect(rel) as rels
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know about this Neo4j plugin.

Comment: @st1led Highly recommended to study this library: many problems that can not be solved with `cypher` can be solved with `apoc`.